# 8K Resolution works only in 30 Hz - How change clock Resolution

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I have a question. I use my Computer at a Samsung 8k Television. I use Dual-Boot. In Windows 8k with 60 Hz on HDMI-2.1 is no Problem. In Ubuntu 22.04 with Nvidia 510 driver it is only possible to use 30 Hz at 8k resolution. The command "xrandr -q" shows me only 8k at 29.997 Hz Resolution. Can anybody explain me, who to add the 8k - 60 Hz resolution in Ubuntu 22.04 to the screes settings. (I use the Nvidia 5.10 .. driver , have RTX 3080 installed). Would be appreciate about an answer, Ingolf

Answer (score 1):

On a similar search to have 8K from Linux I found two discussions with technical info, very different in nature from each other and in tone, with better tech info further down in discussions:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/wg731e/hdmi_sucks_what_can_we_do_about_it/ describes there is friction because the HDMI defining body doesn't allow HDMI 2.1 compatible drivers that are open source.
  And yet, supposedly Nvidia cards may have been working anyway at some point in time.
- https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/8K-display-from-an-XPS-13-with-Ubuntu/td-p/8227685 in speculating "It seems that in order to come out of the [Linux notebook] 8K that in a dock can be converted to HDMI 8K, in order to have low enough bandwidth, the GPU must apply Display Stream Compression (DSC) 1.2," draws attention to the topic "what subunit, the GPU, dock, or adapter provides what compression, and how would the kernel know?"

Maybe that helps you.
Myself I still haven't found anyone saying they got a Linux notebook to work with an 8K TV.  You are running a desktop, right?

Answer (score 0):

Now I installed a new Ubuntu 22.04, once with Nvidia 510 , once with the 520 driver. And it is the same situation. It`s only possible to use 7680x4320  at 29,97 Hz. So it seems to be the Nvidia-Driver.

Comment: It is not clear that this is an answer to your original question.  Perhaps this would be better as an update to your question?